# Is it possible for a moon to orbit a planet floating free in the galaxy rather than orbiting a star

Tags: planet, orbit, exoplanet, natural-satellites

[This article](http://news.yahoo.com/first-exomoon-possibly-glimpsed-110000768.html) got me thinking, can a planet hold a moon in orbit if it is just floating in the galaxy by itself not as part of a star system? Can a celestial body even qualify as a planet if it is floating around by itself?

Comment: Anything can orbit anything. This is just a mass question.

Comment: @RoryAlsop [Not even](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0291), you're such a hopeless traditionalist! :) :P

Comment: @TidalWave this is extremely interesting, I too was a traditionalist until now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.. Planets that don't orbit around a star are known as **Rogue Planets**. There is nothing preventing a rogue planet from having one or many moons.

Not so long ago, the first **candidate for a free-floating exoplanet-exomoon system** was presented in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3951). It looks like a gas giant several times larger than Jupiter with a sub-Earth mass moon.

[Another study](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0945) calculated and simulated scenarios where planets where ejected from their orbits around a star and concluded that around **five percent** of Earth-sized planets who are accompanied by Moon-sized natural satellites would retain them after the event.