# Could rogue planets harbor life?

Tags: exoplanet, life, rogue-planet

On July 21 at 10 am, Seti Talks will be discussing the topic of "Could Rogue Planets Harbor Life". Supposedly there are 50 billion such planets in the Milky Way. I would think that the answer was obvious: no. So what is there to discuss?

Comment: I wouldn't rule out life anywhere in the universe.

Comment: Life doesn't have to take a form in any way similar to what we've previously been exposed to in this world.  When we look at things like the need for water, carbon-based chemistry, etc., these types of natural characteristics are simply based on past experience, not proven laws of the universe.

Comment: Somewhere on a rogue planet - "Could star-bound planets harbor life? Seems unlikely, all that radiation."

Comment: Life, uh, finds a way.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: It's hard to imagine any form of life that doesn't require an external energy source though.

Comment: Primitive life, probably yes. But no way are you evolving the complexity of, say a moth that has *two separate body plans* in it's lifecycle. There is simply way too little energy to get very far.

Answer (score 21):

There's also the possibility that a rogue giant planet may have a moon with a subsurface ocean of liquid water due to tidal heating in an orbit close enough to its parent planet. E.g. if Jupiter was a rogue planet its moon Europa could still harbor life because of tidal heating.

> Around five percent of Earth-sized ejected planets with Moon-sized natural satellites would retain their satellites after ejection. A large satellite would be a source of significant geological tidal heating<sup>26</sup>.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet#Sunless,_yet_warm)

<sub>26. Debes, John H.; Steinn Sigurðsson (20 October 2007). "The Survival Rate of Ejected Terrestrial Planets with Moons". The Astrophysical Journal Letters. 668 (2): L167–L170. arXiv:0709.0945</sub>

Comment: @Pureferret Why would you think rogue planets can't have satellites?

Comment: I thought if a planet was knocked out of orbit, that the moon would be almost certainly knocked away? Is that wrong?

Comment: @Pureferret [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet#Sunless,_yet_warm) *"Around five percent of Earth-sized ejected planets with Moon-sized natural satellites would retain their satellites after ejection. A large satellite would be a source of significant geological tidal heating.[26]"*

Comment: A rogue planet could also pick up moons after being ejected.

Comment: @Pureferret An ejected planet can retain its moon, see my answer here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41832/could-an-orphan-rogue-planet-have-a-moon/41838#41838

Answer (score 13):

In short, if a rogue planet has enough internal heat and retains enough of that internal heat by a thick atmosphere or within a miles-deep ice crust, it could be warm enough for liquid water and thus possibly for Earth-like lifeforms.

here is a link to an article on the subject:

https://futurism.com/life-could-exist-on-rogue-planets-that-dont-have-stars

And an advanced civlization capable of building artifical habitats on lifeless worlds or in outer space could settle a rogue planet, providing their own energy source from nuclear fusion.

Comment: I think you need to trim the end of the link: https://futurism.com/life-could-exist-on-rogue-planets-that-dont-have-stars . Perhaps of interest to the OP, the popular science youtube channel Kurzgesagt had some videos on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLZJlf5rHVs , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7CkdB5z9PY

Answer (score 4):

The discussion will focus on

- the term *rogue planet* is an oxymoron, as it's missing the principle defining feature of a planet.
- a Jupiter-sized body without a sun will be warmer than you would have thought.  And they could be even larger, up to being brown dwarfs.
- moons of such a body can be heated by tidal forces, without regard to whether there's a sun or not.

Comment: I would agree that *rogue planet* is a bad term. In my opinion, "rōnin planet" would be more adequate.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C5%8Dnin